# Calculate mathematical operation stored in String using regex in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I want to evaluate mathematical expression stored in String and print the result.

I have to use Pattern matching in Scala.
I wrote this code below, but it does not work, it prints `false` instead of `2`.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
object PatternMatcher{
    val s = "13 - 5 - 6"
    val Pattern = "((\\d+\\s[+-]\\s){1,10}(\\d+){0,1})".r

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(matcher(s))
    }

    def matcher(choice: String): Any = choice match {
        case Pattern(choice) => choice
        case _ => "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: A capturing group inside a capturing group...? Is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: @Thomas I think yes, because I want to capture whole string. When i used one group( `\\d+\\s[+-]\\s){1,10}\\d+`) i got only `5 - ` as a result, which is the last part of the string matched with the pattern.

Comment: If you try with this: `(\d+\s+[-+]\s+\d+\s+[-+]\s+\d)` (to be escaped) does it work?

Comment: @Thomas Oh, I didn't mention that i want to expand this equation, by adding or subtract more numbers. So your solution works but only for this example, with 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something flexible, this is what you need:

```
((?:\d+\s*[-+]\s+)*\d+)
```

With <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA0nD2/3)</kbd>

Comment: I'm getting exception: `Unknown inline modifier near index 3
((?|\d+\s*[-+]\s+)*\d+)` It points on | (logical OR)

Comment: @user3463645 the regex I gave you is unescaped, you should escape it before using it (using `\ `)

Comment: I can't get it to work, could you write exactly how the Pattern variable should look like.

Comment: @user3463645 my bad. It's a `:` instead of `|`

Comment: Great, now it's working. I have used """((?:\d+\s*[-+]\s+)*\d+)""" so there is no need to escape string.