# Calculate a mathematical expression stored in String - Scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have a String like val s = "5 - 3 + 2" (there can be any number of additions/substractions). Using pattern matching I would like to calculate this expression (so for this example result would be 4). 
My first idea is to do something like this:

```
object calculator{
    val s = "5 - 3 + 2"
    val Pattern = "(\\d+)".r

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val matches = Pattern.findAllIn(s).toArray
       for (mymatch <- matches) mymatch.toInt
       var sum = 0
       matches.foreach(sum += _)
       println(sum)   
    }
}
```

It doesn't even assume that I can have substractions (I don't know how to do this), but there is an error: type mismatch; found : String#3416175 required: Int#1078

Another approach is to have a matcher and somehow evaluate these expressions there:

```
val Pattern = ((?:\\d+\\s*[-+]\\s+)*\\d+).r
def matcher(expression: String): Any = expression match {
        case Pattern(expression) => expression //evaluate expression here?
        case _ => "wrong expression"
    }
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/q/35037985/2988 ?

Comment: The expression isn't calculated there and that's what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your expression contains only additions and substractions you can use something like this:

```scala
val expression = "5 - 3 + 2"

def evaluate(expression: List[String]): Int = expression match {
    case l :: "+" :: r :: rest => evaluate((l.toInt + r.toInt).toString :: rest)
    case l :: "-" :: r :: rest => evaluate((l.toInt - r.toInt).toString :: rest)
    case value :: Nil => value.toInt
}

val expressionElements = expression.split("\\s").toList

val result = evaluate(expressionElements)

println(s"$expression = $result")
```

Detailed explanation how pattern matching works you can find here (http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf) but I try to explain this particular example step by step.

First of all you have to understand how List can be constructed.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3) 
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
(two lists with 3 elements: 1, 2, 3)
```

So our expression is something like this:

```
  val expressionElements = expression.split("\\s").toList  
//val expressionElements = "5" :: "-" :: "3" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil
```

evaluate function supports three cases:

1. addition - `case l :: "+" :: r :: rest =>`
2. substraction - `case l :: "-" :: r :: rest =>`
3. "value" - `case value :: Nil =>`

First `evaluate` call , which is (tail) recursive function, will be something like this:

```
evaluate ("5" :: "-" :: "3" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil) = "5" :: "-" :: "3" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil match {
   case l   :: "-" :: r   :: rest              => evaluate (l - r :: rest)
 //case "5" :: "-" :: "3" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil => evaluate (5 - 3 :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil)
 //case "5" :: "-" :: "3" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil => evaluate ("2"   :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil)
}
```

Second call:

```
evaluate ("2" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil) = "2" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil match {
  case l   :: "+" :: r   :: rest  => evaluate (l + r :: rest)
//case "2" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil   => evaluate (2 + 2 :: rest)
//case "2" :: "+" :: "2" :: Nil   => evaluate ("4"   :: Nil)
}
```

And third call:

```
evaluate ("4"   :: Nil) = "4"   :: Nil match {
  case value :: Nil => value.toInt
//case "4"   :: Nil => "4".toInt
}
```

So expression is evaluated to 4.

Comment: This is great, but can you explain how the matching works? I have some problems figuring that out.

Comment: Detailed explanation in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you would want to do this with a regex? There are other solutions out there...

You could create a far more powerful solution using parser combinators. Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.donroby.com/wp/scala/parsing-expressions-with-scala-parser-combinators-2/) from Don Roby that shows exactly this.

You could use Dijkstra's Two Stack algorithm like in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086296/1274818), or better yet [from Princeton here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Evaluate.java.html).

Comment: See Shunting-yard algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val expr = "2*(2+3)"

val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val calc = toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(expr))
```

The result is

```
calc: Any = 10
```

Comment: Hello @Vasyl I'm using your above code but in that Power operator is not working can you please advise why it is so.